# Make super key trigger ubuntu-gnome-desktop start menu under budgie

Tags: desktop-environments, unity-dash, ubuntu-gnome, budgie, gnome-dash

I'm an avid vanilla ubuntu user (19.04) I've recently switched to budgie desktop environment.

after some tuning using the "Budgie desktop Setting" app (which is basically "Tweaks" such as "gnome-tweaks", but for budgie, I've gotten rid of Plank and tuned my Panel by adding "Icon task list" for one...),  I've obtained what I want : this -> https://github.com/vinceliuice/Qogir-theme#screenshots

However I can't really adapt to the mint / cinamon / windows xp start menu. I've pretty much been onboard with the fullscreen search / "synapse" approach since day one.

and the start menu we've had in ubuntu since ubuntu's adopted gnome is pitch perfect to me.

Am I dreaming too much if I want to ally the best of both worlds (budgie & ubuntu-gnome start/search) ?